# Best way to use Index in Django and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Python, Django and PostgreSQL for my application development. My Database has millions of records and I have to generate reports in real-time (runtime)using those data. While generating those reports the application gets timed out and not able to generate reports. if the data is around 50k it is generating an excel file but when the data is in millions, the query is unable to run.

Which is the best way to implement Index through Django Model or PostgreSQL Index?

Please help me in optimizing the query to make it faster.

*******Version*******

PostgreSQL 13.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

---

```
    EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) 
SELECT
    V."MERCHANT_ID",
    V."ACCOUNT_NUMBER",
    V."GIFT_LIST_REF",
    ( SELECT "store_id" FROM vd_store_master WHERE "store_id" = V."GIFT_LIST_REF" ) AS owingin_store_id,
    ( SELECT "store_name" FROM vd_store_master WHERE "store_id" = V."GIFT_LIST_REF" ) AS owingin_store_name,
    ( SELECT "franchisee_id" FROM vd_store_master WHERE "store_id" = V."GIFT_LIST_REF" ) AS owingin_franchisee_id,
    ( SELECT "franchisee_name" FROM vd_franchisee WHERE "franchisee_id" = ( SELECT "franchisee_id" FROM vd_store_master WHERE store_id = V."GIFT_LIST_REF" ) ) AS owingin_franchisee_name,
    ( SELECT "merchant_name" FROM vd_merchant_master WHERE merchant_id = V."MERCHANT_ID" ) AS merchant_name 
FROM
    vdaccount_card_assign V 
WHERE
    "MERCHANT_ID" = '003561002966107' 
    AND "CARD_STATUS" = 'D'
    
    "QUERY PLAN"
    "Seq Scan on vdaccount_card_assign v  (cost=0.00..2056093.85 rows=149948 width=1362) (actual time=0.144..7171.425 rows=154405 loops=1)"
```

Comment: Start with an index on MERCHANT_ID and all columns related to GIFT_LIST_REF. But the query looks a bit strange as well: Why all these sub selects?

Comment: Hi, @FrankHeikens Thanks for the revert! All these Sub Select because we are fetching data from multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try tuning postgresql itself? It helped me to get the db working quicker.
Go to https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/ and filling all the details you know and it will give you a start setting to play with.

For the INDEX: I guess on each table you need to create at least an index with the id's

Also maybe you can use INNER JOIN instead of the extra SELECT's? Not sure that it will be quicker though.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to create multiple files and try multiprocessing or hyperthreading to help reduce the runtime and the workload. Importing files as modules can help divide the work up but make it messier. You should try:

```
import ex.py, ex2.py, ex3.py... # Duplicate of programs

find() #example function
```

Also, actually how long is the runtime?